# TFS 2012 builds builds mixed configuration instead of release

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, build, tfs

I configured TFS to build my solution in Release|All CPU. When build is done out of 3 project, 1 appears to be in release (no pdb file) while two others in debug (pdf files are present). Any ideas why? I want all to be in Release. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Build Configuration in the Solution - It is possible to configure your "Release" config so that certain projects don't build, or build in different configurations. This is handy when you want certain projects to build slightly differently for each config. It sounds like your solution config is messed up:

- Open your Solution
- Click on Build >> Configuration Manager
- Select Release/Any CPU
- Ensure that each of the projects in your solution have the desired value in the configuration column

[image: Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Go to solution configuration manager and make sure that all projects are built to Release|any CPU. Also, check compile options that it produces or doesn't produce PDB file. The truth is, you want "pdb" even for release but you can keep it aside, so later you can debug production code as needed.